# Scroll for child form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

In the winform it has child forms and I use these codes for being Sorted :

```
this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal);
```

But there is question. This form has 4 child forms when I use that code it will be sorted but there is no scroll or something in the child form so that can let users see all form controls. I want to know how can I use a scroll bar that when form has been smaller we could scroll the child form and see all of its controls.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The language is officially called **C#** - and not `c sharp` or `c-sharp` or anything like that.

Comment: And typically, something like the language used, should be in the *tags* - not the title (you do have the `C#` tag for your question - that's good!)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about those things you have mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Forms AutoSCroll Property to true

Comment: @aliboy38 Make sure you mark the answers as answers, I noticed you have asked a lot of questions and have only accepted one so far.  If you don't accept answers it looks bad for you, and people will stop helping.

Comment: but when form get smaller the scroll will be shown and users can scroll down but it won't show some controls which located in the bottom of the page.

Comment: Are you sure your Form is on your screen?  maximize it.

Comment: I don't want to maximize it. Cause it has other child form too. Is that because of using table layout panel?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to turn on [AutoScroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a62htd5x) on the `Form` to add scrollbar functionality for you.  This technique works with many Windows Forms objects (anything deriving from [ScrollableControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol)).

Comment: but when form get smaller the scroll will be shown and users can scroll down but it won't show some controls which located in the bottom of the page.